# Equivalence of cohomology for local systems

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Let $X$ be a connected CW complex, $\rho:\pi_1(X)\to Aut(G)$ a representation, and $G_\rho$ the associated sheaf. We then have two ways of computing cohomology:

1. The cohomology of the complex $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]}(C_i\tilde X,G)$, where $\tilde X$ is the universal cover of $X$, and $C_i\tilde X$ is the $\mathbb{Z}[\pi_1]$-module of $i$-dimensional cells in $\tilde X$.
2. The sheaf cohomology of $G_\rho$

Under what conditions are these equal, and where can I find a proof of this?

Comment: Bredon's "Sheaf Theory" Ch. III.1 essentially has a proof of this. He relates the sheaf cohomology to singular cohomology with local coefficients. The missing steps left are then (i) moving from singular to cellular and (ii) checking that the complex Bredon is considering can be identified with chains on the universal cover. Both are not so bad.

Comment: Further, if you wan to relate to group cohomology of $\pi_1(X)$, assume that $X$ is $K(\pi,1)$. The standard reference is Brown's "Cohomology of Groups". I also like Raghunathan's book "Discrete subgroups of Lie groups" since he also discusses de Rham theory with twisted coefficients (as well group cohomology and cohomology with sheaf coefficients).

Comment: I'd say this is in Spanier's book.

Comment: Local coefficients are discussed in Section 12.4 of the book" Nonabelian Algebraic Topology", using crossed complexes. Maybe more work needs to be done using the relation with the cohomology of a cover by open sets, see Section 12.5.i.